# Amazon Workspaces create image with user setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

Is it possible to create an image/bundle in Amazon WorkSpaces which keeps the user settings like extensions in the browser or the short cuts in the taskbar or start menu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [Create a custom WorkSpaces image and bundle - Amazon WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/create-custom-bundle.html):

> If you've launched a Windows or Amazon Linux WorkSpace and have customized it, you can create a **custom image** and custom bundles from that WorkSpace.
>
> A *custom image* **contains only the OS, software, and settings for the WorkSpace**. A *custom bundle* is a combination of both that custom image and the hardware from which a WorkSpace can be launched.
>
> After you create a custom image, you can build a custom bundle that combines the custom image and the underlying compute and storage configuration that you select. You can then specify this custom bundle when you launch new WorkSpaces to ensure that the new WorkSpaces have the same consistent configuration (hardware and software).

The image will contain an **exact copy of the disk**. Therefore, it will include user settings.

Comment: It seems not all of the required tools are already installed and some are quit challenging to install. If I find time I'll try to install them all.

Comment: I did not find a NVIDIA-Driver which I can install on my WorkSpace, so I can not install the required component Teradici PCoIP agents and drivers.

Comment: @Marlowe You didn't mention anything about drivers in your question. If you have some questions about this, please create a new Question. Also FYI: [Connecting to Amazon WorkSpaces Desktops](https://www.teradici.com/web-help/TER1504003/6.0/02_Setting_Up/03_Connect_AWS.htm). And try it with a `Graphics` Workspace, since it includes a GPU. (Warning: It's much more expensive!)

Comment: Can not find STXHD agents and drivers to download.
Why this stuff is not installed by default?

Comment: I have had Teradici working with Workspaces, but had to use the Graphics (or Graphics Pro?) workspace type. You might get a better response at: https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

The custom image create an exact copy of software & OS settings you have. I been deploying it to few of users in client environment & so far all softwares installed on my workspace from which i created image are there for users.

> which keeps the user settings like extensions in the browser or the short cuts in the taskbar or start menu

1. so far the taskbar shortcuts in my image were not reflected in other users. They had to create their own shortcuts
2. shortcuts on desktop were retained
3. did not try with browser setting

Additional info: i had few softwares for which i had disabled auto updates. Same was reflected in other users also.

Hope this helps